# React.js pass data between components flow

Tags: reactjs

I have created three basic components.

A renders both the components B and C
B is like header containg tabs 1,2,3
C is the first page on which there are two forms, one shows at a time. On showing first form i need to show tab one 1 in B component. On showing second form i need to show tab 3 in B component.

I just want to pass the data from C component on the basis of which form is showing to B component.

I put state on C component and tried to use same this.state.data or this.props.data for no value coming in B controller.

**A.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import B from './B.jsx';
import C from './C.jsx'
class A extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            show : '1',
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.props.show}
                <B />
                <C/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default A;
```

**B.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

class B extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            show : '1',
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            //html code here
        )
    }
}
```

**C.jsx**

```
class C extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            show : '1',
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            //html code here
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your code, that u tried ??

Comment: @MayankShukla I added some code to understand.

Answer (score 10):

You will need to add your state to parent component here it would be A component then pass a function to change your states to B and C to change your state on A like below

```
class A extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            show : '1',
        };
    }
    changeShow(show){
        this.setState({show: show});
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.props.show}
                <B show={this.state.show}/>
                <C handleChangeShow={this.changeShow.bind(this)} show={this.state.show}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Now you have access to show state in your child components and can change it from them for example in C

```
class C extends React.Component {
    handleChange({target}){
        this.props.handleChangeShow(target.value)
    }
    render() {
        return (
           <select onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
                <option value="0">hide</option>
                <option value="1">show</option>
           </select>
        )
    }
}
```

Now you have access to show state in B

```
class B extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
           {this.props.show}
        )
    }
}
```

It wasn't clear enough what were you trying to do in your example so I tried to give a example how to pass state between child component in a general sense. I hope it would be useful enough

Comment: I got the idea how to props and state works in the parent child here. Thanks

Comment: glade to be of help

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create the same scenario that u described, check the `jsfiddle` for working example.

`jsfiddle` : https://jsfiddle.net/mj8rsawh/

please comment on this if you want any other help.

Comment: can you please describe it once?

Comment: What i understand is add the update function in parent component.
Then pass the initial value to the components with the function binding
<B show={this.state.show} updateShow={this.updateShow.bind(this)}/>
how can i pass two values to it? for example show and hide?
Then inside the chlid component use the bind function to update the value and retrieve it all over the three components.

Comment: I got the idea how to props and state works in the parent child here. Thanks